# Style link while pressed with CSS on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, css

Can I style a link on an iPhone when the user presses and holds it?

Ive used the :hover to style the link when its pressed, but when a user presses a link and keeps it pressed down its highlighted with the default grey. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set its `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` CSS property.